# Strange Outcome of MongoDB Map-Reduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm running a Map-reduce job on a MongoDB collection 2 times a day. It basically counts Orders and puts them in different Categories(Size of package, Delivery Company). The Resulting document is an Object with the Categories as keys and the number of orders as values(integer).

From time to time, the values of the Document become some kind of strange Javascript code.

Here are the first(of over 500) lines of "code":

```
0100function (){ 
var u = {}, a = []; 
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){ 
    if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) { 
    continue; 
    } 
    a.push(this[i]); 
    u[this[i]] = 1; 
    } 
    return a; 
    }1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111function (){ 
    var u = {}, a = []; 
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){ 
    if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) { 
    continue; 
    } 
    a.push(this[i]); 
    u[this[i]] = 1; 
    } 
    return a; 
    }( 052function (){ 
    var u = {}, a = []; 
    for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){ 
    if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) { 
    continue; 
    } 
    a.push(this[i]); 
    u[this[i]] = 1; 
    } 
    return a; 
    }1111111111111111111111111function (){
```

mongod --version returns

```
db version v2.6.10
2015-10-13T15:28:49.990+0000 git version: 5901dbfb49d16eaef6f2c2c50fba534d23ac7f6c
```

MAP Function

```
function () {
var amount = 0;
if(this.hasOwnProperty("articles")){
    this.articles.forEach(function (a) {
        amount += parseInt(a.amount);
    });
}
if(amount>0)emit(amount, 1);
emit("total", 1);
if (amount == 1) {
    emit("1SS", 1);
} else {
    emit("Box", 1);
}
```

Reduce

```
function (key, vals) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i in vals) {
            sum += vals[i];
        }
        return sum;

    }
```

Example Doc

```
{
  "_id": "1SS",
  "value":12
}
```

Comment: What is the map-reduce you are using? What is the collection like? What is a sample of expected outcome? What is the MongoDB version? Any other relevant info? It's hard to help with this little information.

Comment: @Matheus208 I added everything.